# SQL query to PySpark query

Tags: sql, pyspark, databricks

So I'm having trouble converting a SQL query into PySpark. Don't worry, this isn't for anything prod, just thought it would help me learn.

The SQL in question:

```
SELECT count(*)
  FROM orders_bronze_view
 WHERE o_orderdate >= date("1993-07-01")
   AND o_orderdate < date("1993-10-01")
   AND EXISTS (
      SELECT *
        FROM lineitem_bronze_view
       WHERE l_orderkey = o_orderkey
         AND l_commitdate < l_receiptdate
     )

>>>Output: 263 458
```

Where `orders_bronze_view` is a view of my df `orders_bronze`, and likewise with `lineitem_bronze_view` and `lineitem_bronze`

The PySpark:

```
(orders_bronze
      .join(lineitem_bronze, orders_bronze.o_orderkey == lineitem_bronze.l_orderkey, "left")
      .filter( (col("l_commitdate") < col("l_receiptdate")) & (col("o_orderdate") >= lit("1993-07-01")) & (col("o_orderdate") < lit("1993-10-1")) )
      .count() 
)

>>>Output: 726 795
```

I think my issue is my lack of understanding what `EXISTS()` does. I've read that it returns a bool based on the condition, so figured the `filter` condition would've satisfied it, but nope.

Thanks!!

I've checked to make sure counts in dataFrames and Views are equal

Comment: Have you tried using the exists function in pyspark? https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.exists.html I agree that the two queries are not equivalent, you may be able to do this in pyspark without a join. Exists should evaluate to true if the subquery returns one or more rows, false otherwise.

Comment: @MVirts - the `exists` function you're referring to is for array fields.

Comment: @samkart Thanks! I completely misread that page.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best strategy is to filter on o_orderdate before joining with lineitem_bronze, using an inner join to satisfy the requirement that only rows matching lineitem_bronze survive, then filtering on l_commitdate < l_receiptdate.

Without being able to test it, here's my attempt at implementing this in pyspark:

```py
orders_bronze.filter(
        (col("o_orderdate") >= date("1993-07-01")) & 
        (col("o_orderdate") < date("1993-10-01"))
        ).join(lineitem_bronze, 
                orders_bronze.o_orderkey == lineitem_bronze.l_orderkey, 
                 "inner"
        ).filter(col("l_commitdate") < col("l_receiptdate"))
```

This is similar to rewriting your original query like:

```sql
SELECT
    count(*)   
FROM
    ( SELECT
        *   
    FROM
        orders_bronze_view  
    WHERE
        o_orderdate >= date("1993-07-01")    
        AND o_orderdate < date("1993-10-01")) )    
INNER JOIN
    lineitem_bronze_view    
        ON l_orderkey = o_orderkey              
WHERE
    l_commitdate < l_receiptdate
```